# How to check whether an array of array have a key value pair in its values in PHP or Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the following array. I want to know whether any of the values of the array contains the key-value pair `"RoleCode" => "Admin"`.

```
[
  0 => [
    "RoleCode" => "Admin"
    "RoleName" => "Administrator"
  ]
  1 => [
    "RoleCode" => "PM"
    "RoleName" => "ProjectManager"
  ]
  2 => [
    "RoleCode" => "ScheduleUser"
    "RoleName" => "Schedule User"
  ]
]
```

I can write a long code to find it out like the following:

```
$isAdmin = false;
foreach ($user['Roles'] as $role) {
    if ($role['RoleCode'] == 'Admin') {
        $isAdmin = true;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this in a better way?

Comment: Adding `break` will give you optimal solution.

Comment: What would be your end goal if you already know the `admin`? Execute some code inside the "if" statement or capture the value of the admin for a later execution? If you, want to do the former then your current code should be enough. If the latter, then you might have to execute something like `_.find()` then do it outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column) and [`in_array()`](https://php.net/in_array):

```
$isAdmin = in_array('Admin', array_column($user['Roles'], 'RoleCode')) ;
```

- `array_column()` will return an array with all values from `'RoleCode'` key
- `in_array()` will check if `Admin` is inside

Answer (score 3):

It depends what is **better** way.

Current solution with adding `break` when item found:

```
$isAdmin = false;
foreach ($user['Roles'] as $role) {
    if ($role['RoleCode'] == 'Admin') {
        $isAdmin = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

will be `O(n)` in worst case.

Other solutions, like one in another answer

```
$isAdmin = in_array('Admin', array_column($user['Roles'], 'RoleCode'));
```

This will be `O(n) + O(1)` in best case and `O(n) + O(n)` in worst. More than initial `foreach`.

Another one is filtering:

```
$isAdmin = !empty(array_filter(
    $user['Roles'], 
    function ($v) { return $v['RoleCode'] == 'Admin'; }
));
```

It is always `O(n)`

So, from the point of readability and performance, initial code is the winner.